# How to compile glib using gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I have a cross compiler and I know how to cross compile a file.
But I am doing all just for glib compilation that I do not know how to do.
Anyone to guide me.
or generally just inform me how can I compile a complete library using gcc

Comment: You need to be more specific. You should be compiling with a cross-compiled version of 'glib' - and then you need to ensure that any paths will be relative to a cross-compiled 'glib' installation. This question needs more information.

Comment: just inform me how can I compile a complete library using gcc if I am given source files.

Comment: I think that there should be some changing in Makefile of glib then this thing may be possible but I am not certain about this

Answer (score 1):

If the source code of library has a configure script try :

```
./configure --host=TARGET_PLATFORM
```

you must have TARGET_PLATFORM gcc installed .

e.g. : target=arm-linux-androideabi , so you should have arm-linux-androideabi-gcc and arm-linux-androideabi-ar & ... in your $PATH

If the source code does not provide 'configure' then `export CROSS_COMPILE=TARGET_PLATFORM`.

Comment: suppose ABC is path to your cross-compiler(if it's not installed into OS) , use `export PATH=${PATH}:${ABC}/bin`